# Apply 'keypress' function() to next <span> element once the 'keypress' has changed the class of the selected <span> element

Tags: javascript, loops, keypress, repeat

I have taken a string and created a `<span>` for each letter in the string. My goal is to iterate through the spans, take into account the keypress feed back and determine if the keypress is 'correct' or 'incorrect'. Once the appropriate class has been assigned, I would like to preform the same keypress function on the next span element. I can't figure out how to move to the second span. The class applies, but any additional key feedback continues to apply to the first `<span>` element

example:
`<span>e</span>`
`<span>x</span>`
`<span>a</span>`
`<span>m</span>`
`<span>p</span>`
`<span>l</span>`
`<span>e</span>`

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
  var $current  = document.querySelector('span')
  var $next = document.querySelector('span').nextSibling
  if ($activeChar === event.key) {
    $current.classList.remove('current')
    $current.classList.add('right')
  } else {
    $current.classList.remove('current')
    $current.classList.add('wrong')
  }
  return $next.classList.add('current')
 })
```

I am very new to Javascript and I apologize in advance for my lack of understanding, but I want to learn. I have referenced the JS books that I have and searched high and low. I haven't found a solution that I am able to implement on my own. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of defining the keypresses inside of the event listener take the following for a spin:

```js
var out = document.getElementById("output");

document.onkeydown = function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 65) out.innerHTML = "a";
  if(e.keyCode == 66) out.innerHTML = "b";
  if(e.keyCode == 67) out.innerHTML = "c";
};
```

```html
<body>
<span id="output">press either the a, b, or c key</span>
</body>
```

the following uses `e.keyCode` which is fancy for "key value". I find this much easier to do and if you need a list just look at this [keycode info](http://keycode.info)

For you're purpose:

```js
var out = document.getElementById("output");
var subedKey;
var chosenKey;

function start(){
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

  switch(rand){
    case 1:
      chosenKey = "a";
      out.innerHTML = "press the a key";
    break;
    case 2:
      chosenKey = "b";
      out.innerHTML = "press the b key";
    break;
    case 3:
      chosenKey = "c";
      out.innerHTML = "press the c key";
    break;
    default: console.log("no key was chosen");
  };
}

start();
document.onkeydown = function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 65){ out.innerHTML = "a"; subedKey = "a";}
  if(e.keyCode == 66){ out.innerHTML = "b"; subedKey = "b";}
  if(e.keyCode == 67){ out.innerHTML = "c"; subedKey = "c";}
  if(subedKey == chosenKey){
    out.innerHTML = "correct";
  }else{
    out.innerHTML = "incorrect";
  }
  window.setTimeout(start, 2000);
};
```

```html
<body>
<span id="output">the letter is:</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Liam, thank you. Thats a great take on another way to solve this. Didn't know anything about the e.keycode method. Thank you for helping me on my continued quest to learn.

Comment: Anytime! I use this _a ton_ when working with `canvas`, if you ever need me to show you the ropes with that I would be glad to! But if you're getting into game development with HTML and JavaScript definitely look at canvas

Comment: Fantastic. I have heard about canvas but never dug into it. I may very well message you in the future for some insight. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You had a few problems with your code.
First, you would have always selected the first element, and not the current one, so I added a class to your span, and select by it.
Second, you're not defining `$activeChar`
Third, `nextSibling` won't return what you expect. `nextElementSibling` will

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  var $current = document.querySelector('span.current')
  var $next = $current.nextElementSibling
  var $activeChar = $current.innerText
  if ($activeChar === event.key) {
    $current.classList.remove('current')
    $current.classList.add('right')
  } else {
    $current.classList.remove('current')
    $current.classList.add('wrong')
  }
  return $next.classList.add('current')
})
```

```css
.current {
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  background-color: green;
}

.wrong {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class='current'>e</span> <span>x</span> <span>a</span> <span>m</span> <span>p</span> <span>l</span> <span>e</span>
```

Comment: Alexey, you are awesome. Thank you so very much for sharing your knowledge. People like you help me to stay positive in my quest to learn.

Comment: Happy to hear. Please mark as correct answer, if it was indeed one :)